# How to concat strings in .data in opl project?

Tags: cplex, opl

In my .dat I have:

```
string1 = "Hola";
string2 = "Mundo";
```

How can I concat string1 + string2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OPL scripting](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplscripting):

```
string string1 = "Hola";
string string2 = "Mundo";
string string3;

execute
{
  string3=string1+string2;
  writeln(string3);
}
```

gives

```
HolaMundo
```